# How to create test users during development with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I recently started building my first Firebase app, and I'm unsure how to create test users.

For non-user test data, I can keep a `testdata.json` file in my codebase and import it via the Firebase Console, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent mechanism for users.

I'm aware that the latest version of firebase-tools (v3.2.0, released 4 days ago) added an `auth:import` command, but when I checked the [docs](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#auth-commands), I saw that it expected password hashes to be pre-generated, which is not something I know how or want to do manually.

If there was an equivalent `auth:export` command that generated a file appropriate for feeding to `auth:import`, then I could use the Firebase Console to manually create a few users, export them to a file, and check it into my codebase (just like `testdata.json`), but there is no such command.

Even then, the fact that the Firebase Console doesn't let you set basic profile attributes (like `displayName`) on users is yet another obstacle...

Answer (score 5):

There are three ways to create email/password users:

1. through [the API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account)
2. through [the Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/users)
3. by importing them with [the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth-import)

For your use-case all three of these sound equally applicable. If you're having trouble getting one working, edit your question to include the [minimal steps that reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you'd like to request a fourth way, I recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone following along with this post, it appears the Firebase CLI added this export feature:

```
firebase auth:export users.json
```

However it's not clear to me how user password hashes are preserved for `auth:import`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to add *test users* with **JSON + Firebase console**.

0. Go to your project -> develop -> database
1. click menu -> export JSON to see your Db structure
   [image]
2. add new users (or other data) to this JSON
3. Go to your project -> develop -> database and delete your database
   [image]
4. click menu -> import JSON and paste your new JSON-file
5. Now your Db contains test users!

Comment: You misunderstood his question. He is not asking about create user data in Firebase Realtime Database. He is asking about create users in Firebase Authentication.